# TypeScriptにanyは使わない方がいいですか？

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

VSCodeでReactNativeの開発を行なっています、他人の書いたコードにanyというタイプが使われており、lintに引っかかって以下のメッセージが表示されています：

`Unexpected any. Specify a different type.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any`

以下の二つの違いは何ですか、詳しく教えて頂くと助かります。よろしくお願いします。

- `use unknown instead,...`
- `use never instead,...`

Comment: 題名と本文で聞きたいことが違っているように見えます。あなたが本当に聞きたいのは「anyを使用しても良いのか、悪いのか、どうすべきなのか」ですか？それとも「lintのメッセージの内容の詳細を知りたい」ですか？前者の場合は、本文を題名にあわせてください。後者の場合は、題名を本文にあわせて、聞きたい内容のメッセージを中途半端に省略せずに、全文を載せるようにしてください。二つとも聞きたい場合は、質問を分けてください。

Comment: そうでしたね、意図はanyを使わないべきかどうかを聞きたいです、使うべきであればエビデンスがあるだけでそれで大丈夫です、使わないべきであればどれを使うべきかとその違いを教えていただきたいところです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`any`を使用してはならないとTypeScriptの公式のドキュメントに明記されています。

[TypeScript: Documentation - Do's and Don'ts#any](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any)

> **Don’t** use `any` as a type unless you are in the process of migrating a JavaScript project to TypeScript. [...] This can be very helpful when you are first migrating a JavaScript project to TypeScript as you can set the type for stuff you haven’t migrated yet as `any`, but in a full TypeScript project you are disabling type checking for any parts of your program that use it.
>
> In cases where you don’t know what type you want to accept, or when you want to accept anything because you will be blindly passing it through without interacting with it, you can use `unknown`.

以下、私訳です。

> JavaScriptのプロジェクトをTypeScriptに移行している最中ではない限り、型に`any`を使用**しないでください**。〔中略〕JavaScriptのプロジェクトをTypeScriptに移行する時に、まだ移行していないものの型をとりあえず`any`と設定できるため、初期の頃はとても役に立つのですが、TypeScriptプロジェクトとしては、`any`を使用している部分の型チェックが無効なままになってしまいます。
>
> 受け入れたい型がわからない、または、どのような物に関わらず取りあえず何でも受け入れたい時は、`unknow`が使用できます。

TypeScriptの強力な型チェックの効力を十分に受けたいのであれば、`any`は使ってはいけません。公式な使い方としては、JavaScriptからの移行途中などで取りあえず動かしたいという場合に、仕方が無く使うという程度のもののようです。また、どんな型がなのかよくわからないという場合でも`any`を使うべきではなく、代わりに`unknown`が用意されています。

ただ、実際の所、型を指定していくのが面倒だからとりあえず`any`にするということは、個人の小さなプロジェクトでは少ないないと思われます。(個人的には、型を一々書くのが嫌ならJavaScriptで書けば良いじゃんと思うのですが…)

Comment: ありがとうございます。